# Docker Desktop closed unexpectedly

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-desktop

I installed Docker Engine and Docker Desktop following the advice in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72299444/docker-desktop-doesnt-install-saying-docker-ce-cli-not-installable/72411734#72411734) on a virtual machine of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

And for a simple test, the command `sudo docker run hello-world` returns `Hello from Docker!` so I believe Docker Engine is working correctly.

However, Docker Desktop is not working, and the system log `/var/log/syslog` keeps popping the below errors until "The application Docker Desktop has closed unexpectedly".

```
May 31 12:12:57 dockerub ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[3194]: Docker Desktop1, Impossible to lookup icon for 'Docker Desktop1_842-panel' in path /tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.Mxd55e
May 31 12:12:57 dockerub ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[3194]: unable to update icon for Docker Desktop1
May 31 12:12:58 dockerub ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[3194]: Docker Desktop1, Impossible to lookup icon for 'Docker Desktop1_848-panel' in path /tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.nNdyiR
May 31 12:12:58 dockerub ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[3194]: unable to update icon for Docker Desktop1
May 31 12:12:59 dockerub com.docker.backend[11585]: [2022-05-31T18:12:59.229343880Z][com.docker.backend][W] still waiting to update HTTP proxy on http-proxy-control.sock after 1m31.111144268s. Last error was Post "http://localhost/vm/httpproxy": dial unix <HOME>/.docker/desktop/http-proxy-control.sock: connect: no such file or directory
May 31 12:12:59 dockerub com.docker.backend[11585]: [2022-05-31T18:12:59.233717551Z][com.docker.backend][W] 5e9fe131-PauseHDL /pause/events server not replying: Get "http://ipc/pause/events": dial unix <HOME>/.docker/desktop/procd.sock: connect: no such file or directory
...
```

We will highly appreciate any suggestions or hints. For any more details, please let me know.